# IIS6 caches a renamed folder - can this be flushed/reset?

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

On a Windows2003 server I have two folders:

- Forum
- Forum_dev

The Forum folder is live and actively used. The dev folder contains a number of changed ASP files. Renaming Forum to something else and changing Forum_dev to Forum seems to ignore the changed files. Is there a way to force IIS to clear its cache?

I think I can go through the changed files (in the new Forum folder), make a change and save the file and it's ok, but there are a lot of files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming the root physical folder is probably not helping since the app holds on to that folder.  You could name it "pink elephants" it won't care it only needs the name when looking up the folder when starting the application.

The correct and friendly approach is simply to recycle the application pool the application is in.  You can do this from the context menu on the pool in IIS manager.

Don't use IISRESET its seriously draconian compared to recycling.

Comment: Whilst I agree that IISRESET is the path of last resort (I should know, I work for a hoster) if all your websites are in a single pool then you may as well get medievil in the server. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this fixed the problem or not, but that or saving changes to the files seems to have fixed it for the users. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use brute force and do:

```
c:\> IISRESET
```

Not nice but should get the job done.

Are you absolutely sure that it's IIS caching these pages and not the browser clients?

Comment: I can't be sure. By changing the files on in the newly renamed forum folder that seemed to fix the problem which implies the server is at fault.